# devops local agent specific permission

Tags: command-line, azure-devops

I have local instance that connect into SUT hardware, the operation is to copy files into SUT, create folder on SUT.

manual on local instance the operation work but when execute from agent i got permission denied.

```
E PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '//192.168.1.100\\c$\\'
```

I'm tried to execute the command via command line on the agent

how can I solve this issue ?
what is the method to handle this cases?

Comment: Use the Windows Machine File Copy task to copy files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) to copy files by providing the credential to access the target path.

For command line, you can try to grant the **Read** and **Write** permissions for the build agent service account (Which you specified during deploy the agent), then try it again.

Besides, you can also create a script to copy the files, then add a command line or PowerShell task to run the script.

For example, you can use below PowerShell script to copy the sources files with the specific username and password provided:

```
$Source = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
$Dest   = "\\192.168.1.100\CopyTest"
$Username = "domain\username"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
New-PSDrive -Name J -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Dest -Credential $mycreds -Persist
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Recurse -Force -Destination $Dest
```

Comment: The problem is that the copy is in automation script with python , and i can only call the test that run python script

Comment: Could you elaborate how did you define your build pipeline?